# PYTHON How to access the index of the first and last of consecutive boolean values (or 1's and 0's) in a list/series/dataframe

Tags: python

I stumble about a certain problem a lot and usually build complicated solutions to solve it but I think there might be a very easy solution that I don't know of.
Let's consider the following minimal example:

```
# create some data
x = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)  
y = np.sin(x)

# add a condition (-0.25 < y < 0.25)
limit=[1 if (y[i] > -0.25) & (y[i] <0.25) else 0 for i in range(len(y))]
```

The list called limit now consists of 0's and 1's. There are always 5 consecutive 1's in a certain intervall. I would like to know the index positions of the respective first and last 1 of each intervall.

Maybe a plot helps to clarify

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(2,constrained_layout=True)

ax1[0].plot(x,y)
ax1[0].vlines(x=x[29], ymin=-1, ymax=1, linestyle='--')
ax1[0].vlines(x=x[33], ymin=-1, ymax=1, linestyle='--')
ax1[0].set_title('data')

ax1[1].plot(x,limit)
ax1[1].set_title('condition')
```

[simple plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3aTa.jpg)

How to get the x values of each condition offset?

Comment: How about using numpy.diff and see where the output of that is non-zero?

Comment: Yes, that works! But only for numerical values. Is there an elegant way for boolean values as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with the borders is a bit annoying. You might want to adjust this to your specific needs. Anyway, something like this might be okay for you:

```py
condition = (y > -0.25) & (y < 0.25)
padded = np.concatenate(((False, ), condition, (False, )))
print(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(padded)).reshape((-1, 2)))
```

If you want more control about where ranges start and stop, computing the diff explicitly is a good start.

```py
rising = np.flatnonzero(padded[1:] & ~padded[:-1])
falling = np.flatnonzero(padded[:-1] & ~padded[1:])
print(np.dstack((rising, falling)))
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your feedback! Based on your answers I solved the minimal example using np.diff() (code is below). I will think about another minimal example where strictly boolean values are required, but for now this is solved and helped me solve my actual problem.

```
import numpy as np

# create some data
x = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)  
y = np.sin(x)

# add a condition (-0.25 < y < 0.25)
condition=[1 if (y[i] > -0.25) & (y[i] <0.25) else 0 for i in range(len(y))]

# use np.diff
limit=np.diff(condition)
limit_start=np.where(limit==1)
limit_end=np.where(limit==-1)

#plot
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(2,constrained_layout=True)

ax1[0].plot(x,y)
ax1[0].vlines(x=x[limit_start], ymin=-1, ymax=1, linestyle='--')
ax1[0].vlines(x=x[limit_end], ymin=-1, ymax=1, linestyle='--')


ax1[0].set_title('data')
ax1[1].plot(x,condition)
ax1[1].set_title('condition')
```